# Php configuration file using loader class for multiple branches

Tags: php, symfony, build, release

I have multiple branches and need to have different configuration based on the branch. I am using prepend loader class for configuration purpose.I would like to know the best way to do this. I have 2 options with me please provide suggestions regrading those as well.

`1. Give the branch name as argument in the loader.`

`2. Check the PWD and similar parameters in the loader class`

Any suggestion on this context is appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use following php function:

```
    realpath($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

This will provide the path which can then be exploded to get the branch name. This solution is working fine since couple of weeks, so I am sure that this is the easiest and safest way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `AppKernel.php` file into symfony2. Into this file will be this function

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
  $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
```

You can "hack" this function for your need.

Obviously you have to "import" (`use` statement) a file where you specify the "rules" for load the correct file.

Comment: I have legacy non symfony code as well in my branch, please suggest how I can manage in that case.